# Is there an Eclipse module to place semicolons in PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse

The java editor options for eclipse include an option for automatically placing a semicolon at the end of a statement if you type it anywhere in the line.

Eclipse PDT does not seem to have a similar option for PHP. Is anyone aware of a module that adds this capability (or any other way to avoid having to manually move the cursor out of a nested set of parens to add the statement terminator?

Comment: Did you try the [END](http://sillydog.org/graph/ss/apple/keyboard_home_end.png) key on your keyboard? :)

Comment: I'm assuming you were being intentionally humorous, but in case you were not, I'll give a serious answer. That obviously works, but it requires moving the hands from the home position on every single line of code. Hence the reason they added the automatic semicolon option for the Java editor. I'm hoping there is an easy means to do similar for the PHP editor. If not, it might motivate me to learn enough about Eclipse development to make one.

Comment: Of course I was being ironic...My point is, I've been developing php for years, on several IDEs (Eclipse being the latest), and though I enjoyed autocomplexion, brackets and quotes autoclosing and other features, I never saw something like you ask; I'm wondering: why and how do you have so many lines without a semicolon at the end (syntax errors)? Why don't you add it manually (I mean, it comes out of pure habit after a while, like indenting in python) when you're done writing the rest of the line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the PDT doesn't support such functionality.

For Java you can find it under **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing** and here **Automatically insert at correct position: Semicolons**.
However there's **no such option** under **PHP -> Editor -> Typing**.

As far as I'm aware at one point someone had an idea of implementing this feature, however PDT team in recent years is really struggling (you most likely work on Eclipse Helios PDT which is based on a Helios release of Eclipse from 2010, while current version of Eclipse is Juno from mid 2012, and Eclipse team is working on moving into the Kepler release) so I wouldn't count on this feature being implemented in any foreseeable future.

As far as I'm aware - there's also no additional plugin to support such functionality in PHP.